# Property 'key' does not exist on type > 'LiHTMLAttributes'.ts in Astro component

Tags: arrays, typescript, astrojs, array-map

I am using Astro and typescript and having this code which returns a navigation:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="flex gap-x-12">
    {
      menuItems.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.title}>
          <Link to={item.url}>{item.title}</Link>
        </li>
      ))
    }
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I get this typescript error on the `key` prop:

> Type '{ children: any; key: string; }' is not assignable to type
> 'LiHTMLAttributes'.   Property 'key' does not exist on type
> 'LiHTMLAttributes'.ts

How do I solve this issue? From the [astro docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/migrate-to-astro/from-nextjs/#guided-example-next-data-fetching-to-astro) I should be able to add the `key`?

Or is `key` not needed in Astro arrays and should I somehow configure the ESlint differently?

Comment: `key` can be removed as it isn't required in Astro. You can also remove `Link`, and use an `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

I think Astro manages the keys for each items under the hood, so you don't have to provide a key prop. (the reason you can't is because astro syntax changes any HTML global attributes)

```
<nav> 
  <ul class="flex gap-x-12">
{
  menuItems.map((item) => (
    <li>
      <Link to={item.url}>{item.title}</Link>
    </li>
  ))
}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

".map just works!" -> https://astro.build/